# Expanding column width based on maximum value in row in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with several columns and I'm looking into expanding the columns based on the value in each row.

If the value in the row is greater than the column width then expand to the width of the row value.

However, the code below expands the columns based on the value from one column and sets the width to all of them.

```
Dim j As Integer, m As Integer
    With tRange.Columns
    .AutoFit

        m = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Columns(1).ColumnWidth

        For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
            If .Columns(j).ColumnWidth > m Then m = .Columns(j).ColumnWidth
        Next j

        .ColumnWidth = m
    End With
```

Is there a way to have the column width based for each column and set the width individually rather than setting the width globally?

Hope you know what I mean!

Comment: Try to draw what you are looking for and you should see that it is not possible since it is a matrix. You can use Merge Cell option maybe to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

To autofit the column for a single `Range` you can use a `Sub` like the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    AutoFitRangeColumn Sheet2.Range("B4")
End Sub

Sub AutoFitRangeColumn(ByVal rng As Range)
    rng.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your entire code with

```
tRange.Columns.AutoFit
```

That will set each column within your range ("tRange") to the appropriate size for that column.